# Handling A List of model in the view using classic ADO.Net approach -MVC Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Good day to all. I have a partial view with few labels and text boxes. Combination of each holds an instance of my model class and finally an update button(Edit+update).

My model is a List of Attribute(class)

```
 public class Attribute
 {
    public int id {get; set; };
    public string AttributeName {set;get; }
    public string AttributeValue {set; get; }
 }
```

Initially my partial view load the default values from the database and will the displayed on the respective text boxes. Currently what I am looking for is to perform Edit and update (not in a new partial ) .
i.e , whenever AttributeValue(TextBox) encounters a change, on click of the  update button the changes need to be communicated to the database. I prefer single

```
 update (Edit id)
```

to

```
 update(List<Attribute> attr)
```

This question is more towards design. Ideas and help appreciated.

As an additional note this is how my partial view roughly looks like

```
  <label> @attrname = > Name </label>
  <input type = "text" value = "Name Value/ >
   <label> @attrname = > Age </label>
  <input type = "text" value = "Age Value"/ >
  <input type="submit" />
```

On click of this update button the existing unmodified values needs to preserved and new values need to updated. I have seen tutorials with Edit on a different partial view but I wish to accomplish the above in the same view.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you need a loop in your action method to iterate through list

Comment: Hi .. problem is not in displaying . It is on how to  preserve the list value and communicate the changes to the database  the code I have  presented above for the view part was just a sample not actual implementation

Comment: Nothing here will post back because none of your inputs have a name attribute (and you wont be able to name them correctly using a partial view anyway). Are you wanting the POST method to be `public ActionResult(IEnumerable<Attribute> attributeCollection)` so you can save a collection of `Attribute` to the database?

Comment: Although sending individual attribute is my preference , I m still fine with sending the whole collection..

Comment: If you want to edit and save an individual `Attribute`, you might be better off to have a display only page (`Index() method`) for the collection that  includes an action link adjacent each item which redirects to an `Edit()` method where you can edit and save the `Attribute` then redirect back to the `Index()` method.